# Microsoft Help Viewer 2.3 error File was not signed by microsoft

Tags: visual-c++, help-viewer

everytime i try to download books in Microsoft Help Viewer 2.3 it shows error message "An error occurred while updating content: File `file location` was not signed by Microsoft"

any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is still present in the latest VS 2017 (January 2020) and Microsoft continues to claim they can't reproduce the problem.  Waiting for an official fix will probably never happen and I didn't want to do an hour-long uninstall, followed by day-long layout-update, followed by an hour-long re-install, all to arrive at the same issue.

I wrote an article illustrating the steps I used to work around the bug. The work around is to bypass the Microsoft root CA check.  A download patch is available for Help Viewer version 2.3.28107.0.

[Article Link](http://bytepointer.com/articles/vs2017_help_not_signed_by_ms_fix.htm)

Hopefully I can save others the time and hassle.